# QGIS no geom-columns found .. there is a genometry column

Tags: qgis

I have a database that keeps information for world map. When I  export this to  Quantum the map that is shown is not full. How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but your question is a little vague.  What database are you using? How is the coordinates stored (can I assume decimal degrees, or are you using PostGIS and have a geometry column)? What geometry type are you trying to show?

If your DB is postgresql / postgis with a geom column,  then you can select "Add Vector Layer" and check the "Database" radio button under "Source Type". You can then create a connection to that table and it will load the data just fine.
Alternatively, select the "Add PostGIS Layers" option and create a connection that way.  You can follow the same steps if your database is MS Access etc and you can connect via ODBC.
If it doesn't then I think your issue will be in the database.

This part assumes you have point data:
If your database is excel, make sure your coordinate columns are the right data type and it is saved as .csv.
Select "Add Delimited Text Layer" in QGIS and you fill in the details for which are the X and Y coordinate columns. If you have a lot of columns it make things easier if your column headers are 'X' and 'Y' respectively.

Finally (again assuming point data) you could open the processing toolbox and search for 'Points Layer From Table'. If you don't see the processing button along the top of QGIS, then you've got to download it from the plugins manager (just search 'processing').  You need to state the layer, X field, Y field, and your CRS and that will create a new layer. NOTE the data is now separate from the database so any changes made to the layer are not reflected in the database.  Unlike using PostGIS where the updates are live.

I hope this has helped, sorry if this has been a memory dump of all the ways I know without knowing a little more about your issue.